# Conflict between amsmath and pdfcomment

Tags: cross-referencing, amsmath, incompatibility, pdfcomment

I use both `amsmath` and `pdfcomment` in one document. This leads to the references produced by `(\ref{})` to appear like `(zref@1)` instead of numbers like `(1)`. Without `amsmath` or `pdfcomment` this problem does not show up.

A minimal (not) working example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{hyperref} 
\usepackage{pdfcomment}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\label{eq:1}
E = m \pdftooltip{c}{speed of light}^2
\end{equation}

See eq. (\ref{eq:1}). % <- this produces (zref@1) instead of (1)

\end{document}
```

Compile it with `pdflatex`.

Any suggestions are very welcome.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is not really to do with `pdfcomment`, except that one is more likely to use a `\pdftooltip` inside an equation than, say, a `\section` command.  But if you were so foolish as to try:

```
\begin{equation}
\label{eq:1}
x^2 + y^2 = z^2
\section{Pythagoras}
\end{equation}
```

then (assuming it actually compiled, which I doubt) you would find exactly the same problem.

It is due to the fact that when `amsmath` processes an equation environment, including the `equation` one itself (since it redefines it), then it does some Complicated Stuff on the equation which involves processing it a few times over (this causes Issues with beamer and tikz as well, I believe).  One consequence of this is that if you put a `\label` command in an equation environment then the label is not saved right away, rather the equation is processed at least once before the label is saved to the `.aux` file.  This is presumably to deal with things like `align` where more than one piece of the whole equation contents can be labelled (I'm guessing here).

Now the `\label` command figures out what information to save by using the value of `\@currentlabel`.  This is a neat piece of work, and it's what ensures things like `\section{Introduction}\label{sec:intro}` Just Works(TM).  But this does mean that you need to ensure that between when the counter is incremented and the `\label` command is processed then the the `\@currentlabel` doesn't get redefined.

Here's where `amsmath`s wizardry works against it.  If there is a command inside the equation which increments a counter in such a way that the `\@currentlabel` is redefined then it is *that* which gets saved rather than the equation label.  My silly example with `\section` is one such command, but that's unlikely to appear in an equation environment.  Another is `\pdftooltip` and that, as we see, is a little more likely.

To verify that what I'm saying is true, we can simulate the `\section` command:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\renewcommand{\thesection}{\alph{section}}

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}
\label{sec:intro}

\begin{equation}
\label{eq:1}
E = m c^2
\refstepcounter{section}
\end{equation}

See eq.\ \ref{eq:1} in Section~\ref{sec:intro}.

\end{document}
```

This produces:

> See eq. b in Section a.

If we comment out the `\refstepcounter` line, we get:

> See eq. 1 in Section a.

As another experiment, we can remove `amsmath` and get the problem with the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdfcomment}

\renewcommand{\thesection}{\alph{section}}

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}
\label{sec:intro}

\pdftooltip{hello}{world}

\label{sec:introb}

Sections~\ref{sec:intro} and~\ref{sec:introb} are the same.

\end{document}
```

In this case, the answer is simple: make sure you issue the `\label` before the `\pdftooltip`.  But for the `amsmath` situation, things aren't so easy because everything is internal.

Looking in the source of `pdfcomment` I can see that `\pdftooltip` uses `\refstepcounter` which is the magic command which resets the `\@currentlabel`.  My guess is that it only needs to use it internally, and afterwards it doesn't need to have `\@currentlabel` set to anything particular.  So the *best* solution would be to patch the `pdfcomment` so that it saves the current value of `\@currentlabel` when invoked and restores it again afterwards.

However, I don't recommend patching packages yourself.  So you should contact the maintainer of the package and ask him to do so.  In the meantime, there is a way to get around the problem.  This is simply to ensure that the correct `\@currentlabel` is in force at the end of the equation.  So we need to call `\refstepcounter` but without actually incrementing the counter.  Here's a simple macro that does that:

```
\makeatletter
\def\refsetcounter#1{%
    \protected@edef\@currentlabel
       {\csname p@#1\endcsname\csname the#1\endcsname}%
}
\makeatother
```

Call it as `\refsetcounter{equation}`.  It has to be placed at the **end** of the equation environment (or at least, after the `\pdftooltip`).

Now, it would be nice to have this done automatically.  This would involve patching the `amsmath` commands.  Normally, I'd be wary about this as well, but I feel a little more on sure ground with the `amsmath` package than the `pdfcomment` one so I'm prepared to have a go!

My experiments show that it is actually only the `equation` command that has this problem.  Somehow, things like `align`, `gather`, and `multline` work just fine.  So we only need to ensure that our new command, `\refsetcounter{equation}` is run at the end of the `equation` environment.  Here's the code for that:

```
\makeatletter
\def\refsetcounter#1{%
    \protected@edef\@currentlabel
       {\csname p@#1\endcsname\csname the#1\endcsname}%
}
\let\orig@endequation=\endequation
\def\endequation{%
  \refsetcounter{equation}%
  \orig@endequation}
\makeatother
```

With this in the preamble, your code produces:

> See eq. (1).

As it should.

Comment: Andrew, this was a very interesting read, though I confess, that I'm not latex literate enough to understand your code. It seems that the problem here is almost identical in nature to a problem that I posted here to do with markup in figure captions: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/42960/1269 . I tried your temporary solution using `\refsetcounter{figure}` in figure captions, and also at the end of the figure environment, but this didn't work. I'm guessing that different variables are involved.

Comment: @aghsmith I've had a look at your question and it certainly looks similar enough.  However, the figure environment doesn't work in the same way as the equation one so even if the problems are the same then the solutions may be different.