# Problem when using pdfcomment in figure captions and then referencing

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, cleveref, pdfcomment

This is possibly a bug in the `pdfcomment` package, maybe not. I use the `\pdfmarkupcomment[]{}{}` macro to insert highlighting into the caption of a figure. Then follows a lable. I reference the figure using `\autoref` or `\cleverref`. In both cases the referencing fails and I get a warning:

> LaTeX Warning: cref  reference format for label type `zref@unique' undefined on input line 14.

Here is code for this example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdfcomment}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\begin{document}
   \begin{figure}
      \caption{\pdfmarkupcomment{Hello}{}}
      \label{fig:myLabel}
   \end{figure}

\cref{fig:myLabel}
\end{document}
```

Now I know something about this. The highlighting works by inserting hyperlinks/labels into the text and it looks like there is a conflict between the ones inserted into the caption and the label that I create after the caption.

Is there a fix for this?

**EDIT: --- (note I changed the quote, and the load order of the two packages as well)---**

I've put a bit more effort into this and improved my understanding of the problem, though not to the point of finding a solution

The "undefined" warning that I had previously is to do with `pdfcomment` inserting tags of type `zref@unique` which are analogous to tag types of `figure` or `table`.

I used the following modified code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdfcomment}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\makeatletter
\crefname{zref@unique}{CLEVERzref}{CLEVERzrefs} % defining name for cleverref
\newcommand{\zref@uniqueautorefname}{AUTOzref}  % defining name for autoref
\makeatother

\begin{document}
   \begin{figure}
      \caption{\pdfmarkupcomment{Hello}{}}
        \label{fig:myLabel}
   \end{figure}

   cleverref: \cref{fig:myLabel}

   autoref: \autoref{fig:myLabel}
\end{document}
```

to get the following output with no warning messages:

[image]

So the current unknown is when referencing, why both `cleveref` and `hyperref` locate the `pdfcomment` tag within the comment block instead of the label they are given.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the same underlying problem as with the question [Conflict between amsmath and pdfcomment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28313/conflict-between-amsmath-and-pdfcomment), namely that `pdfcomment` uses the label system internally and doesn't clean up after itself.  The reason that the solution from that question doesn't work is that you are using `hyperref` and `cleveref` which both add stuff to the label-reference system and that has to be taken into account: it's not enough to just reset `@currentlabel` anymore, you have to reset `@currentHref` and `\cref@currentlabel` as well.  `hyperref` defines an internal command that sets its stuff correctly, so we just have to call that, `cleveref` doesn't (as far as I can tell) so we have to copy the new definition of `\refstepcounter` to a command `\refsetcounter` which does the same except that it doesn't increment the counter.

Here's a copy of the code that does that, so far as I can tell!

```
\documentclass{article}
%\url{https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28313}
%\url{https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/42960/86}
\usepackage{hyperref} 
\usepackage{pdfcomment}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\makeatletter
\def\refsetcounter{%
  \@ifnextchar[{\refsetcounter@optarg}{\refsetcounter@noarg}%]
}
\def\refsetcounter@noarg#1{%
  \cref@constructprefix{#1}{\cref@result}%
  \@ifundefined{cref@#1@alias}%
    {\def\@tempa{#1}}%
    {\def\@tempa{\csname cref@#1@alias\endcsname}}%
  \protected@xdef\cref@currentlabel{%
    [\@tempa][\arabic{#1}][\cref@result]%
    \csname p@#1\endcsname\csname the#1\endcsname}%
  \hyper@makecurrent{#1}%
}
\def\refsetcounter@optarg[#1]#2{%
  \cref@constructprefix{#2}{\cref@result}%
  \protected@xdef\cref@currentlabel{%
    [#1][\arabic{#2}][\cref@result]%
    \csname p@#2\endcsname\csname the#2\endcsname}%
  \hyper@makecurrent{#2}%
}

\crefname{zref@unique}{CLEVERzref}{CLEVERzrefs}
\newcommand{\zref@uniqueautorefname}{AUTOzref}
\let\orig@caption=\caption
\def\caption#1{%
  \orig@caption{#1}\refsetcounter{figure}%
}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\caption{%
\pdfmarkupcomment{Hello}{}%
}
\label{fig:myLabel}
\end{figure}

cleveref: \cref{fig:myLabel}

autoref: \autoref{fig:myLabel}
\end{document}
```

At the very least, it produces what I would expect to see with your test document.

Comment: Thanks very much for this solution Andrew. It does work in the example I gave. I have found some problems though when implementing it in my thesis. The first is that there seems to be a kind of conflict with the `caption` package (there are warnings). Though the actual consequence of this is not clear. The other is that the `\caption[LOF comment]{text comment}` macro will no longer support its optional argument. Using one, breaks the referencing again and also messes up the formatting of the caption.

Comment: I've tried to contact the `pdfcomment` package author about this problem. From the package developer point of view, is it as simple as telling it to save and reset the `\@currentlabel` as you suggested in your original solution:  Conflict between amsmath and pdfcomment?

Comment: The caption package is going to add yet another layer of things that need to be sorted out!  At this point, I would seriously consider hacking the `pdfcomment` package myself.  I forgot (or didn't know) that `\caption` can take an optional argument so didn't build that in to my solution.  It's possible to fix this.  Possibly the most elegant is to use the `patchcmd` stuff from the etoolbox package, but I've never used that myself.