# Workaround for citation inside pdfcomment?

Tags: bibliographies, pdfcomment

Is there a simple workaround for using citations inside a pdfcomment? Here it is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdfcomment}

\begin{document}

Works \cite{Smith1959}.

Works \pdfmarkupcomment{here}{comment1}

Doesn't work \pdfmarkupcomment{here \cite{Smith1959}}{comment2}.

\begin{thebibliography}{100}
\bibitem{Smith1959}J. Smith, J. Chem. Phys. {\bf 3}, 764 (1935).
\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

The error message is:

```
! Argument of \@citex has an extra }.
```

Comment: No problem here (under TeX Live 2011 on [ShareLaTeX](http://sharelatex.com)). Perhaps related to packages versions?

Comment: @Werner, my versions are: `This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.13 (TeX Live 2013/dev)` and `\ProvidesPackage{pdfcomment}[2012/09/28 pdfcomment.sty v2.3a - Josef Kleber (C) 2008-2012]`

Comment: Same error (and 19 more) with MiKTeX 2.9 and unchanged given MWE (exact: `This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.4-1.40.13 (MiKTeX 2.9) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2013.4.5`, `pdfcomment 2012/09/28 pdfcomment.sty v2.3a`).

Comment: For reference, ShareLaTeX reports `This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.3-1.40.12 (TeX Live 2011) (format=pdflatex 2012.2.4)` and `pdfcomment.sty 2012/01/25 pdfcomment.sty v2.2a - Josef Kleber (C) 2008-2012` and compiles without problem.

Comment: @Werner, yes, it is a big mistery. ShareLaTeX works but not my versions, and they are not that different.

Comment: @Werner, maybe ShareTeX does some modification of code behind the scenes? (for example to `protect` `cite`, see Marco's answer).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems that cite is fragile. However you can do two things:

1. Put `\protect` before `\cite`

   ```
   \pdfmarkupcomment{here \protect\cite{Smith1959}}{comment2}.
   ```
2. Put extra curly braces around `cite`

   ```
   \pdfmarkupcomment{here {\cite{Smith1959}}}{comment2}.
   ```

Comment: thanks, both worked and give the expected output. It is still a mystery that ShareLaTeX (or some version of TeXLive accepts the original code). Perhaps ShareTeX does some modification of the code behind scenes.