# issues with pdfmarkupcomment - whenever it contains another latex command

Tags: errors, hyperref, annotations, pdfcomment

I have been having issues with `pdfcomment` package. Specifically with `\pdfmarkupcomment`

This works fine:

```
\pdfmarkupcomment{text}{comment}
```

This does not work:

```
\pdfmarkupcomment{text with \qty{1}{\percent}}{comment}
```

and gives:

```
! Argument of \\pdfmarkupcomment has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.6 ...false]{replication server \qty{1}\percent}}
                                                  {what is this?}
? exit
No pages of output.
Transcript written on mwe1.log.
```

**MNWE**

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article} % see docs!
\usepackage{pdfcomment}
\usepackage[ngerman, USenglish]{babel} % main language comes last!
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
\pdfmarkupcomment[markup=Highlight, disable=false]{replication server \qty{1}\percent}}{what is this?}
\end{document}
```

Any ideas if I can do something about it? Or is there a different and functional package that would provide ability to insert comments and annotations into `pdf?`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the answers [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/127562/208544) and [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/117392/208544) it seems the issue is that the argument is passed to a command from the `soul` package, which has problems with some input. You can fix it by placing the `\qty{1}{\percent}` in braces:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article} % see docs!
\usepackage{pdfcomment}
\usepackage[ngerman, USenglish]{babel} % main language comes last!
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
\pdfmarkupcomment[markup=Highlight, disable=false]{replication server {\qty{1}{\percent}}}{what is this?}
\end{document}
```

Note that in your post you are missing the second `{` in `\qty{1}{\percent}`.